# Java HTMLUnit and html2canvas to generate image "Cannot modify readonly property:"

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using HTMLUnit in java to download live generated image in javascript/html2canvas.
When heading to browser everything works perfectly fine, image gets downloaded instantly.

When trying to download using HTMLUnit I get the same error multiple times, resulting in a empty corrupted png file.

Java code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
                        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
                        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
                        URL url = new URL(url);
                        HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage(url);
                        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
                        Page image = webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
                        InputStream is = image.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
                        File f = new File(path + "/generatedPic.png");
                        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
                        int b = 0;
                        while ((b = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                            os.write(bytes, 0, b);
                        }

                        os.close();
                        is.close();
```

The error stack i get:

```
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine] Error during JavaScriptEngine.init(WebWindow, Context)
TypeError: Cannot modify readonly property: constructor. (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js#20)
prototype: HTMLOptionElement
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine] Error during JavaScriptEngine.init(WebWindow, Context)
TypeError: Cannot modify readonly property: constructor. (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js#20)
prototype: MutationObserver
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine] Error during JavaScriptEngine.init(WebWindow, Context)
TypeError: Cannot modify readonly property: constructor. (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js#20)
prototype: URL
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine] Error during JavaScriptEngine.init(WebWindow, Context)
TypeError: Cannot modify readonly property: constructor. (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js#20)
prototype: HTMLOptionElement
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine] Error during JavaScriptEngine.init(WebWindow, Context)
TypeError: Cannot modify readonly property: constructor. (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js#20)
prototype: MutationObserver
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine] Error during JavaScriptEngine.init(WebWindow, Context)
TypeError: Cannot modify readonly property: constructor. (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js#20)
prototype: URL
[15:19:59 WARN]: [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument] close() called when document is not open
```

.

Using Java 16 and HTMLUnit 2.5.2
Probably someone knows quick help?

Comment: This is a known bug of HtmlUnit for a long time now - see https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1897/ maybe i will find some time to work on this.